# how to set UseDataContractJsonSerializer in .net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

I follow this [wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_media_type_formatter)  to use `DataContractJsonSerializer` to deserialize json media type request data, but it is for .net framework, I am looking same way for .net core web api.

I need to update the default `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` to `DataContractJsonSerializer` instead of Json.NET. I know I should do change on Startup.cs in

```
 [public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)],
```

but can not find which class is a counterpart part of  `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter`

I believe i need to implement an Inputformatter class:

```
    public class CustomizedJsonInputFormatter : InputFormatter
{
    public CustomizedJsonInputFormatter()
    {

       // this.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
        this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
    }

    protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        if(type == typeof(CreateJobRequest))
        {
            return base.CanReadType(type);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var type = context.ModelType;
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        try
        {
            MediaTypeHeaderValue requestContentType = null;
            MediaTypeHeaderValue.TryParse(request.ContentType, out requestContentType);

            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(type);
            object result = serializer.ReadObject(context.HttpContext.Request.Body);

            return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(result);
        }
        catch
        {
            return await InputFormatterResult.FailureAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

But I get 204 No Content error when use postman to send get request, actually the controller method had handle the request successfully.

Comment: .net core can use DataContractJsonSerializer, it is in System.Runtime.Serialization.Json assembly. the problem is I want to use it as the input formatter to do serialize/deserialize instead of the default Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: i guess I need to add customized input formatter: